# Trigger maestro detalle

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

tengo unos triggers funcionando bien, pero tengo problemas para el rollback. Tengo una estructura de tabla:
Producto: id, Nombre, Precio, Stock
Venta: id, IDCliente, Fecha, Estado
VentaDetalle: id, IDProducto, Precio, Cantidad, SubTotal

En la tabla VentaDetalle, evento insert:
begin
update producto set Stock=producto.Stock-new.Cantidad
where new.IDProducto=producto.IDProducto;
end

En la tabla VentaDetalle, evento deleted:
begin
update producto set Stock=producto.Stock+old.Cantidad
where old.IDProducto=producto.IDProducto;
end

Funcionan bien, pero... cuando necesito hacer el rollback eliminando una venta y que se devuelva el stock a productos, solo lo realiza cuando elimino ventadetalle, pero si elimino desde venta no se dispara el evento.
Tengo el fk en la tabla ventadetalle referida a venta con eliminacion en cascada.
Como puedo solucionar el de que al eliminar venta y se eliminan tambien en ventadetalle se dispare el trigger de ventadetalle tambien.
Saludos!

Comment: Recordad la limitación en los disparadores (triggers) de MySQL: los disparadores no se activan por acciones de claves foráneas ([Chapter 1 Restrictions on Stored Programs::Restrictions for Triggers: Triggers are not activated by foreign key actions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions)).

Comment: Entonces? tengo que pensar en un store procedure?

Comment: Un procedimiento almacenado puede ser una opción, otra opción, dependiendo de sus requerimientos, puede ser eliminar la acción referencial `ON DELETE CASCADE` de la tabla `VentaDetalle` y crear un nuevo disparador (trigger) `BEFORE DELETE` en la tabla `Venta` donde haga el `DELETE` de la tabla `VentaDetalle`, así se ejecutará el disparador (trigger) de la tabla `VentaDetalle`.

Comment: @wchiquito Esto ultimo lo veo mas viable porque no me complicaria ya que no tengo un manejo  avanzado en mysql. Podria ayudarme a como podria hacer esto ultimo?